# Python PRAW Reddit. Raising Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'format'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, reddit, praw

So the program ran through this part of the code WITHOUT ERRORS at least 30 times before and I've run the program multiple times before and never got this error.

What could be the issue?

I recently added a part of the code where if "if keyword['keyword'] == 'testing something':" then it will do "checkkw = checkkw.splitlines()" instead of "checkkw = checkkw.split()" that's the only change I've made and this error popped up, however, I'm not sure how this change could have been the cause of the error.

````
for submission in search_reddit:
                print(submission.title, submission.id)


                ###creating dict
                topics_dict = { "title":[], \
                "score":[], \
                "id":[], "url":[], \
                "comms_num": [], \
                "created": [], \
                "body":[]}
                ### finish dict

                ### insert to dict
                topics_dict["title"].append(submission.title)
                topics_dict["score"].append(submission.score)
                topics_dict["id"].append(submission.id)
                topics_dict["url"].append(submission.url)
                topics_dict["comms_num"].append(submission.num_comments)
                topics_dict["created"].append(submission.created)
                topics_dict["body"].append(submission.selftext)
                ### finish inserting to dict
                if keyword['keyword'] == 'testing something':
                    checkkw = keyword['checkkw']
                    print(checkkw)
                    checkkw = checkkw.splitlines()
                    print(checkkw)
                    total = len(checkkw)
                else:
                    checkkw = keyword['checkkw']
                    checkkw = checkkw.split()
                    total = len(checkkw)

                [elem.lower() for elem in checkkw]
                [elem.lower() for elem in topics_dict['body']]

                print(total)
                print(checkkw)

                exists = 0
                if all(item in " ".join(topics_dict["body"]) for item in checkkw):
                    print('posting')
                    link = topics_dict['url'][0]
                    print(link)
                    result = self.dblinks.get(Query()['link'] == link)
                    if result is not None:
                        print('already posted to this link')
                    else:
                        try:
                            reply_template = keyword['comment']
                            reply_text = reply_template.format(topics_dict["url"])
                            submission.reply(reply_text)
                            self.dblinks.insert({'link': link})
                            time.sleep(1)
                        except Forbidden:
                            print('Error')
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the error that is raised that your problem is with

```
reply_text = reply_template.format(topics_dict["url"])
```

this is likely because a dictionary or list does not have a format function that they can utilize. This line is trying to access a dictionary/list element and format it with another dictionary value which is improper.

Instead, you need to properly access the element (dictionary by key or list by value) to use the element and use it with your `topics_dict["url"]` value